# WooCommerce - wrong Product saved in Order

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

i have a shop running on the latest WC release. I've cross checked the following error via disabling all plugins, and switching themes.

```
A Consumer adds products to his cart. Cart looks fine
He Proceeds to Checkout. Cart looks fine
He processes payment und places his order. Cart looks fine
After the order has been received, a wrong Product is saved in the Order, all E-Mails are wrong, and the subtotals are calculated on the wrong product. Only the correct produt-name is shown, whilst prices and skus are from the wrong (always the same) product.
```

What i have already checked :

- Deactive all Plugins except WC
- Use Default Theme
- Clear all Transient Caches

Any Ideas?

Thanks

Florian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this one was really tricky.

- The initial store was setup via a migration from xt:commerce.
- So all historical orders where migrated to Woo.
- There where several entries in woocommerce_order_items and woocommerce_order_itemmeta tables which had double or misleading keys
- i did a backup of theses tables, truncated/emptied and magic happend ...